# Should I disable interrupts when executing code from RAM?

Tags: c, ram

I am building an update function that completely erases my program code running out of program flash, and flashes a new image in its place.  To accomplish this it is necessary to copy the update function into RAM and branch to it in its RAM location to perform the actual erase/program functions.

```
void update(){
  //Erase flash
  //Program flash
}

void main(){
  // ...

  ramfunction = copytoram((int)update);
  ramfunction();
}
```

This process seems like it should be working to me but for some reason when I run through it, it is failing.  I seem to be able to step through it with the debugger, but when I run it fails.

Should I be protecting `ramfunction();` by disabling interrupts perhaps?  I do have other tasks running in the background. Are there any other probable issues?

Thanks so much!

Edit - All other tasks are running from flash. The update function is linked to run from flash also but I can successfully copy it to ram and branch to it. I can even step through it (at least the disassembly code), it is only when I run through it that I have problems.

Comment: I find this a very interesting question although it may get closed because it is pretty broad.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Presuming the necessary details will be added, it still will not be generally applicable. There are just too many variables for this subject.

Comment: What can I provide you with to make it more specific?

Comment: Are the other tasks running from flash?  Do the interrupts vector to code in flash?  Is the update function position independent, or was it linked to run from ram, even though it was loaded in flash?  Does the update function (or any other task) use any constants stored in flash?  Is this a multi-core CPU, where disabling interrupts would not stop tasks on other cores?

Comment: Yes, all other tasks are running from flash.  The update function is linked to run from flash also but I can successfully copy it to ram and branch to it.  I can even step through it (at least the disassembly code), it is only when I run through it that I have problems.

Comment: Is main running from flash?  If so, when ramfunction returns (does it?), it will not be to the same code that called it.

Comment: So, if the other tasks are running from flash, it will not be good if you switch the code out from under them.  All tasks must be prevented from running (and never allowed to start again).  Also, the ramfunction must not be allowed to return to code in flash which is now different.  The update function should basically reboot at the end.

Comment: @pat That is fine.  At the time the update function is called I can perform a manual reset and be fine.

Comment: I would make sure that the code is position independent or linked to run at the ram address.  You may be getting lucky with it just working, but it would be better to be explicit about it.  Otherwise, a future change to the function may cause it to break mysteriously.

Comment: @pat I suspect that it will not return correctly because I will be giving it a new image with functions in potentially (likely?) different locations.  And that is fine, I can do a manual reboot at that point.  All that matters is that the new image gets programmed into flash correctly.

Comment: What is the CPU doing while waiting for someone to hit the reset button (is that what you mean by manual reset?).  It should not be allowed to run garbage code, it should go into a spin loop at the end of update in RAM.  Better yet, the update function should jump to the reset vector (possibly setting any registers to specified reset values) so manual intervention is not required.

Comment: @pat there is a reset handler that should catch any garbage code and reset the processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have other tasks running simultaneously it is possible that they are interrupting the programming phase of ramfunction.  This could result in catastrophic failure. I would try something like this:

```
void main(){
  // ...

  ramfunction = copytoram((int)update);
  disable_interrupts();
  ramfunction();
  enable_interrupts();
}
```